# Does creating a nonclustered index on a SQL Server 2005 table prevent selects?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, locking

I'd like to create an index on a view I have but I need to make sure the data can still be read while the index is being created.  I was reading an [article](http://sqlserver-qa.net/blogs/perftune/archive/2008/01/25/3285.aspx) that suggested that when creating a nonclustered index that the data is still readable if you specify the ONLINE=ON option (example below):

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CLUST_IDX_SQLTIPS
ON SQLTips (tip) with (ONLINE=ON)
```

Am I understanding this correctly?  Is there any potential issues I should be aware of before I create indexes on a view that needs to be readable while I create my index?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Online index creation and rebuild are available only on Enterprise Edition. See [How Online Index Operations Work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191261.aspx) and [Guidelines for Performing Online Index Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190981.aspx).

There are some restrictions, most notable ones being:

- clustered index must be created/rebuilt offline if they contain any BLOB fields (image, ntext, text, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), and xml).
- intitial clustered index on a view must be created offline.

You must ensure your database have enough space to perform the online index operation, as it requires about 1.5 times the size of the table in *addition* to the current size. During the online index creation the table exist twice in the database, hence the extra space needed.

Since your case falls in the **excluded** category (initial clustered index on a view) then you need not worry about online indexes. You must use an offline index operation.

BTW you must also be aware that indexed views are considered by the optimizer only in Enterprise Edition. On lower editions one must specify the NOEXPAND clause in the view to leverage a possible index on the view.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize that.  I plan on creating two indexes on this view, the initial clustered that you mentioned and a nonclustered after that.  Do you know of anyway to keep the data in my view readable while I create the initial clustered?

BTW I am running enterprise edition.

Comment: The clustered index view will lock rows in the table, thus blocking reads of the locked rows (under default serialisation level). How big is the table? Are we talking few seconds or some hours of index creation time? You may consider enabling read commited snapshot, this will allow the SELECTs to go ahead unaffected. But this has a global impact on the system, specially on tempdb, so you should definetely test beforehand.

Comment: The table has over 9 million records.  I'm thinking that the indexes would take about 15 mins to create.  If people cannot read for 15 mins then i'd have a problem.  Could you be more specific about the impact that enabling read commited would have on the system?  How would you recommend testing before hand?

Comment: You may also consider creating a database snapshot and temporarily redirect the connections to that. Depends on how many updates the database will receive during the operation and whether the application has to show these recent updates or not. If the app can live, for the duration of the operation, with an image of the database at the moment you start the operation (ie. the 'snapshot'), then you can definetly use this.

Comment: Read committed snapshot: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175095.aspx . Impact on tempdb: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175492.aspx

Comment: The database is used for reporting and is only updated once per night.  I am working on getting a snapshot to work on but it's looking like that might take a couple of days and I'd like to try a few things in the mean time.

Comment: `create database foo as snapshot of bar` is almost instantenous. There is no copy involved, the snapshot uses the OS sparse files API to make a copy-on-write on a page-by-page basis of the original database. Is perfect for reporting.

Comment: Note that some of the LOB limitations have been removed in SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2):

There's more information on the msdn articles about [CREATE INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) and [online index operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191261.aspx) that has lots of information about it.

There should be no issues with it, if you're only doing SELECTs and UPDATEs. Not so sure about backups, maybe best to try it on a test system and see?